# An Strange UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath behaviour

Tags: uitableview, scroller

When I Use 
    [self.chatContentTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:bottomFlag+2 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

when the animated set YES,my tableView will scroll,but when the animated set NO,it donest work

Comment: It should be working... Check it properly.... The cell might be coming to center of the Simulator Screen

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but it donest work,and another person say:it may affected by the other Animation

Answer (score 0):

I also found it.

My code is:

```
 [self.tableView reloadData];
 [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:animation];
```

It work after remove `reloadData`.
I guess the reason why it does not take effect is that it's executed immediately after reload